# BlackBerry PhoneGap App call to a PHP don't work

Tags: blackberry, cordova, cross-domain, blackberry-webworks

I have created a single web page with a form which calls a PHP, to get some data from it. But when i make an app of this webpage through PhoneGap and download on Blackberry phone . it does not receive any data. At the same time, when, i see my web page through the blackberry browser I can view my webpage with the required data. What could be the possible reason?

This index.html (for PhoneGap)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mobile </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="http://lowenstern.com.ar/test.php" method="post">`enter code here`
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

config.xml (for PhoneGap or WebWorks from and example in BlackBerry Developer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="2.0"
        rim:header="RIM-Widget: rim/widget">

  <author href="http://www.example.com/"
          rim:copyright="Copyright 1998-2012 My Corp">My Corp</author>

  <rim:navigation mode="focus" />

  <name>Sample application</name>

  <description>
    A sample application to demonstrate some features.
  </description>

  <rim:orientation mode="auto"/>

  <rim:loadingScreen backgroundImage="background.png"
                     foregroundImage="foreground.gif"
                     onLocalPageLoad="true">
    <rim:transitionEffect type="zoomIn" />
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <icon src="icons/example.png"/>

  <rim:cache maxCacheSizeTotal="2048" maxCacheSizeItem ="256" />

  <content src="index.html" ></content>

  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>

  <access uri="http://lowenstern.com.ar" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.pim.memo"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.app"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.MemoArguments"/>
  </access>

  <rim:connection timeout="25000">
    <id>TCP_WIFI</id>
    <id>MDS</id>
    <id>BIS-B</id>
    <id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
    <id>WAP2</id>
    <id>WAP</id>
  </rim:connection>

  <license>
    Example license
    Copyright (c) 2012 My Corp.
    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
    EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
    OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
    NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
    HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, 
    WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, INSULT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING 
    FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR 
    OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
  </license>

</widget>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP directly from the Phonegap app?

Comment: so so, in fact i'm trying to receive "Hello World" from it

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to run php from the index.html which is not possible. There is nothing to interpret the php.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are the main suspect here. Check your `config.xml` file and make sure you have the correct `access` entries. Remember this one:

`<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />`

Is supposed to disable domain restrictions but won't work with ajax calls. So make sure you add an `access` element for your domain.